# New to Maven, what command should I run to build reddison

Tags: maven, redis, reddison

I am trying to build `https://github.com/mrniko/redisson`

When I run mvn, it gives a error

> No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format : or :[:]:. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean. -> [Help 1]

If I use something random `mvn deploy`, the jar files are created in the target folder, but

```
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.1:deploy (default-deploy) @ redisson ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10:11.837s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Sep 23 17:12:52 IST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 29M/113M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.1:deploy (default-deploy) on project redisson: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter -> [Help 1]
```

Just curious, what is the correct `mvn` command ?

Comment: Just run `mvn clean install`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven is a build tool  which by itself doesnt know anything unless you specify using command line or set some defaults in pom.xml

You should typically use  "mvn clean install" as mentioned earlier too to generate the necessary executable

"deploy" goal is used to push your  jar/artifacts to the MAVEN REPO   which is a different server  -  this server holds artifacts and is not a SCM like github or SVN 
 So as the ERROR indicates you need to specify the details of the MAVEN REPO server in your   POM file  or in the setting.xml file of your maven execution